# Errorbars in open circle symbols

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like the gray dots not appear at all inside open circle symbols when I use plt.errorbars. I found a similar question but it uses ggplot.

[Error bars show through open symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066711/error-bars-show-through-open-symbol)

I would like to stick with pyplot unless there is no option. My code is the following. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
yerr = np.random.randint(2,size=len(x))
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr, color='gray', fmt='.', zorder=1)
plt.plot(x,y,'ro', mfc='none', label='My work')
plt.legend(numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `fmt='o'`:

```
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr, color='gray', fmt='o', mfc='white', zorder=1)
```

Include `mfc='white'` to set background color of marrker as white.

See [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for other `fmt` characters.

Comment: In order to make it look like the circle markers are "open" and still hide the errorbars, you should also include `mfc='white'` seeing as how the background also is white.

Comment: @nordev, Thank you comment. I added mention about `mfc`.